# is it possible to use a readonly class as a DTO for symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, php-8.2

I have a simple symfony form used to create a `ThingEntity`.

I have a `CreateThingType` and a `CreateThing` DTO:

The DTO

```php
namespace App\DataTransfer;

use App\Validator\UniqueNameForParent;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\GreaterThan;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;


#[UniqueNameForParent]
readonly class CreateThing
{

    function __construct(
        #[GreaterThan(0)]
        public int    $parent,

        #[NotBlank]
        #[Length(min: 3, max: 6)]
        public string $name,
    )
    {
    }

}
```

The Type:

```
namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\DataTransfer\CreateThing;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CreateThingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('parent', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CreateThing::class,
        ]);
    }

}
```

And a simple controller to handle the thing:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\ThingEntity;
use App\Form\Type\CreateThingType;
use App\ThingRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

#[Route('/create')]
class CreateController extends AbstractController
{
    function __construct(private readonly ThingRepository $thingRepository)     {}

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CreateThingType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $thing = $form->getData();
            
            $thingEntity = new ThingEntity(
                id: null,
                parent: $thing->parent,
                name: $thing->name
            );
            $this->thingRepository->save($thingEntity);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_thing_list');
        }

        return $this->render('create.html.twig', [ 'form' => $form ]);
    }

}
```

When the form is not submitted, the form displays correctly:

[form ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnSRT.png)

But when I submit the form, I get an error, and it looks like this:

> Too few arguments to function App\DataTransfer\CreateThing::__construct(), 0 passed in /U/a/symfony-form-dto-shared-repro/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php on line 134 and exactly 2 expected

I can make it work by removing the `readonly` keyword and making the arguments/properties optional, by having empty default values (which I would prefer not to, since I'd like the DTO to be clear about that "everything is required" when I reuse it elsewhere)

Is it possible to use a readonly DTO with Symfony forms? How?

Comment: While creating the form, where do you provide the required parameters for the constructor of the dto?

Comment: Not really. When the data is submitted the form will set each property individually. It knows nothing about the constructor and it updates whatever entity you passed to it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of the `PropertyAccessor` to know about your constructor. You could have changed the variables names, or apply them differently in the constructor.

As far as I know symfony uses the `PropertyAccessor` component to set the properties to the data_class by either using setters or by setting the properties if they are public. Any of which will not be able to set your Dto as readonly.

I also don't think this would be possible at all with Symfony Form, since you are able to set default values, which are overwritten by your form by using setters or using the public properties of your Dto's which is done by the PropertyAccessor component.

So in short, skip the readonly part and the constructor and create simple Models with getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is possible, you need 2 things to do so. You need to be able to create the empty data for your form and you need to be able to map a form's data to your object and back to the form.

The exception that you get is from the failure of the [default empty_data](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/87186b2c6956d9985c97a1004012ba477a4f72ea/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L134) creation you need to override it by [configuring the empty data yourself](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/form/use_empty_data.html#forms-empty-data-closure), for this I'd recommend creating a [form type extension](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/form/create_form_type_extension.html) or a parent class.

For the data mapping you need to [create a data mapper](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/form/data_mappers.html#creating-a-data-mapper) that can handle the constructor arguments, using a denormalizer should probably be good enough for mapping from the data to the object. Implementing the object to form direction should be easier. If you find a way to use the default mapper for this direction the implementation could just simply call the default.

Comment: This is a bit vague/generic. Can you provide a fuller example?